Understanding Gauss' Law with Spherical Symmetry
I've been working on a problem involving the electric field inside a hollow sphere with known inner/outer radii and a volume-charge density $\rho=\frac{k}{r^{2}}$.
I start with Gauss' Law as normal:
$\oint_{S}^{}(\overrightarrow{E} \circ d\overrightarrow{a}) = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon_{0}}$
I have no trouble finding the enclosed charge $Q$, but when I look at solutions for the left-hand side of the equation, they appear to "skip" the integration and set it equal to $E(4\pi r^{2})\widehat{r}$. I get that the spherical symmetry makes the $\widehat{r}$-direction the only one worth calculating for, but I'm at a loss as to how they get the rest of the expression. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious, but can't quite place it.
Many thanks in advance for any help you all can offer!

and what is the enclosed charge at $r$?

After you finish this, go and prove to yourself that spherical symmetry implies that the E field only has the radial direction component. i.e. prove that the other directions would be unphysical.

$\vec E = E\,\hat r$ and $\vec a = da \,\hat r$ where $\hat r$ is the unit vector pointing out from the origin and is perpendicular to the area $d\vec a$.
You are evaluating $\displaystyle \oint_{\rm S} E\,\hat r \cdot da \,\hat r = \oint_{\rm S} \underbrace E_{\rm constant} da = E\underbrace{\oint_{\rm S} da}_{=4\pi r^2}$.
$4\pi r^2$ is the surface area of a sphere of radius $r$.

To add to Farcher's answer, here's an outline of how you would prove that $\vec E=E(r)\hat r$.
In general, a continuous symmetry (translation, rotation) allows you to get rid of a coordinate dependence. A mirror symmetry constrains the direction of the electric field in the plane of symmetry.
To start, let us assume full coordinate dependence, i.e.
$$\vec E(r,\theta, \phi)=E_r(r,\theta,\phi)\hat r+E_\theta(r,\theta,\phi)\hat\theta +E_\phi(r,\theta,\phi)\hat \phi.$$
Rotational symmetry implies that I can rotate around any angle and $\vec E$ will stay the same. For rotations involving $\theta$ this means
$$\vec E(r,\theta+a,\phi)=\vec E(r,\theta,\phi)\quad \text{for all $a$}.$$
This implies that $\vec E$ does not depend on $\theta$: $\vec E(r,\theta, \phi)=\vec E(r,\phi)$. A short proof
\begin{align}
&f(x+a)=f(x)\quad\forall a\\
&f(x+a)-f(x)=0\\
&\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}=0\\
&\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d x}=0\\
&f(x)=\text{constant}.
\end{align}
The same hold true for rotations around $\phi$, so we have $\vec E=\vec E(r)$. Note that this does not imply that $\vec E$ points in the $\hat r$ direction yet. For example, in 2D, the vector $\vec E=\pmatrix{y\\-x}=r\hat \theta$ is rotationally symmetric, yet does not point in the radial direction.
Finally, mirror symmetry implies that for points inside the plane of symmetry, the vector lies within the plane of symmetry. If we pick such a point, we can decompose the vector into $\vec E_\parallel$ and $\vec E_\perp$, where the former lies in the plane of symmetry while the latter is perpendicular to it. Mirror symmetry implies $M\vec E=\vec E$, where $M$ is the mirror transformation. The proof is now simple
\begin{align}
M\vec E&=\vec E\\
M\vec E_\parallel+M\vec E_\perp&=\vec E_\parallel+\vec E_\perp\\
\vec E_\parallel-\vec E_\perp&=\vec E_\parallel+\vec E_\perp\\
-\vec E_\perp&=\vec E_\perp\\
\implies\vec E_\perp&=0
\end{align}
For a problem with spherical symmetry, for each point of interest we can pick an infinite number of planes with mirror symmetry that pass through the radial direction, i.e. through the line connecting the point and the origin. This means that the field points in the radial direction, although we need just two planes to do it.
